# Worklight: Adapter versioning

Tags: adapter, versioning, ibm-mobilefirst

I want know that is it possible to create **multiple versions of one adapter** as we do for Apps? and deploying all different versions of the same adapter on Console? so that App v1.0 will use adapter 1.0 and the Apps v2.0 will use adapter v2 and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no versioning for adapters.

Right now your "best" approach would be to create multiple adapters with the updated procedures.

Comment: Okay, Yes this could be the approach. I was thinking that creating multiple adapter will increase burden in future when managing different Apps within a same project (WAR, console). Thanks

Comment: Suppose that I have a very big application and some adapters call each other ! What can I do about this ?

Comment: Uh, what do you want to do about it? What's the problem? Open a new question.